# PeerConnection cannot create an answer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am getting this error in my `catch` block when I do `myPeerConnection.createAnswer()`

> PeerConnection cannot create an answer in a state other than
>   have-remote-offer or have-local-pranswer.

I am using **socket.io** as the signalling server. I am following the tutorial from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling)

Here's my code:

```
myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(() => {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
  }).then((stream) => {
    localStream = stream;
    document.getElementById("localVideo").srcObject = localStream;
    return myPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  }).then(() => {
    return myPeerConnection.createAnswer(); //No error when removed this then chain
  }).then((answer) => {
    return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer); // No error when removed this then chain
  }).then(() => {
    socket.emit('video-answer', {
      sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription
    });
  }).catch(handleGetUserMediaError);
```

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595325/webrtc-peer-connection-can-not-create-an-answer) didn't helped me either.

I have uploaded the whole project on Github. You can look at the script file [here](https://github.com/SL-A-SH/Webrtc-Test/blob/master/public/scripts/webrtc.js).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in the tutorial they use `local_video` as the element Id, did you change yours?

Comment: @CodyG. Yes, I changed it in the Html too.

Comment: Is this in Chrome? They have a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=665200). Try it in Firefox.

Comment: @DragonBorn Hi, were you able to find a fix for this? I am also facing the same problem in chrome. It works fine in firefox.

Comment: @helloworld Yes i did find a fix. I even created a basic working application. I have uploaded the file [here](https://github.com/SL-A-SH/VideoAppointment/blob/master/client/src/components/video/startOneToOneCall.js). Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @DragonBorn Thanks a lot. I will have a look.

Comment: @DragonBorn I am not able to figure out what change you did. Can you please let me know why the issue was coming in chrome and what you did to fix this. Understanding from the code is kinda difficult for me.

Comment: @helloworld In chrome the `negotiationneeded` event was getting fired twice when it should get called once. I stopped using `onnegotiationneeded` overall and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

This is long-standing a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=665200) I filed a year and a half ago.

You're creating a peer connection in both the `onclick` handler and `handleVideoOfferMsg`, complete with an `onnegotiationneeded` handler that calls `createOffer`. That's OK and straight out of the [spec example](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#peer-to-peer-example-with-media-before-signaling).

In `handleVideoOfferMsg` you go on to call `setRemoteDescription(desc)`, bringing that peer connection to `have-remote-offer` state, and then you add tracks to it for your answer.

The bug in Chrome is that adding those tracks fire the `negotiationneeded` event, when the [spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dfn-update-the-negotiation-needed-flag) 
 says to only set the negotiationneeded flag in `"stable"` state.

Try it in Firefox. It should work there.

You can work around this in Chrome somewhat, like this:

```
pc.onnegotiationneeded = e => {
  if (pc.signalingState != "stable") return;
  ..
}
```

Comment: Yup it did work for me on firefox without giving any errors and I tried your work around for Chrome but it still gives me the same error. I guess I have to wait for Chrome developers to fix that bug.

Comment: @DragonBorn Sorry for dropping the ball. Yes, there are actually *two* bugs in Chrome here. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035315/918910) for a workaround for both.

Answer (score 3):

Metaphorically speaking, you are trying to answer a question without being asked a question. This does not make sense -- and the peerconnection API tells you exactly that.

Comment: But I did create an `offer` first then sent my local description and in the response I am creating an `answer`. You can check the the whole script file in the link in the question.

Comment: looks like I need to get new glasses, i missed that. what is myPeerConnection.signalingState before you call createAnswer? Also check if the setRemoteDescription call happens twice. This might happen due to Chrome triggering the negotiationneeded event too often.

Comment: Yes the `setRemoteDescription` for the **callee** is being called twice. I have no idea why. How can I prevent that to happen? And since it is being called twice the value for `myPeerConnection.signalingState` is **have-remote-offer** first time and **have-local-offer** the second time.

Comment: ah... you are calling createPeerConnection both in the onclick handler and handleVideoOfferMsg. Both times you are adding a negotiatonneeded handler which will call createOffer. This is the wrong behaviour in handleVideoOfferMsg.

Comment: @PhilippHancke that should be fine once Chrome fixes [their bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=665200).