# How to set remote description for a WebRTC caller in Chrome without errors?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp, peer-connection, rtcpeerconnection

I hope there is no flaw in the logic.

**Step 1:** caller creates offer

**Step 2:** caller sets localDescription

**Step 3:** caller sends the description to the callee

//------------------------------------------------------//

**Step 4:** callee receives the offer sets remote description

**Step 5:** callee creates answer

**Step 6:** callee sets local description

**Step 7:** callee send the description to caller

//------------------------------------------------------//

**Step 8:** caller receives the answer and sets remote description

And here is the code for the above

```
const socket = io();
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: true
};
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
    "url": "stun:23.21.150.121"
  }, {
    "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
  }]
};

const selfView = $('#selfView')[0];
const remoteView = $('#remoteView')[0];

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

pc.onicecandidate = ({
  candidate
}) => {
  socket.emit('message', {
    to: $('#remote').val(),
    candidate: candidate
  });
};

pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
  try {
    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
    socket.emit('message', {
      to: $('#remote').val(),
      desc: pc.localDescription
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

pc.ontrack = (event) => {
  // don't set srcObject again if it is already set.
  if (remoteView.srcObject) return;
  remoteView.srcObject = event.streams[0];
};

socket.on('message', async ({
  from,
  desc,
  candidate
}) => {
  $('#remote').val(from);
  try {
    if (desc) {
      // if we get an offer, we need to reply with an answer
      if (desc.type === 'offer') {
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(desc);
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
        selfView.srcObject = stream;
        await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer());
        console.log(pc.localDescription);
        socket.emit({
          to: from,
          desc: pc.localDescription
        });
      } else if (desc.type === 'answer') {
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(err => console.log(err));
      } else {
        console.log('Unsupported SDP type.');
      }
    } else if (candidate) {
      await pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});


async function start() {
  try {
    // get local stream, show it in self-view and add it to be sent
    const stream = await requestUserMedia(constraints);
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
    attachMediaStream(selfView, stream);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

socket.on('id', (data) => {
  $('#myid').text(data.id);
});


// this function is called once the caller hits connect after inserting the unique id of the callee
async function connect() {
  try {
    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
    socket.emit('message', {
      to: $('#remote').val(),
      desc: pc.localDescription
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

socket.on('error', data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Now this code throws an error while executing **Step 8**

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on
>   'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong
>   state: kHaveLocalOffer
>
> DOMException: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on
>   'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate

Tried to debug but didn't find any flaw in the logic or code. Noticed one weird thing that the the `pc` object has `localDescription` and `currentLocalDescription` and i think the callee who creates the answer must have both the description type to be `answer` but instead shows the `localDescription` to be `offer` and `currentLocalDescription` type is `answer`.

[image]
I have no idea if it is supposed to behave like that or not as I am begginer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is correct. This is a long-standing [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740501) with `negotiationneeded`.

I've instrumented it in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/zehrtbgd/) (right-click and open in TWO adjacent windows, then click call in one).

In Firefox, it works. The offerer negotiates once because you add two tracks (video/audio) at once:

```
negotiating in stable
onmessage answer
```

and, on the answerer side, the tracks you add outside of `'stable'` state are added to the answer:

```
onmessage offer
adding audio track
adding video track
```

But in Chrome, it's broken, firing `negotiationneeded` twice on the offerer, once per track added:

```
negotiating in stable
negotiating in stable
onmessage offer
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
  Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveLocalOffer
onmessage offer
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
  Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveLocalOffer
onmessage offer
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
  Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveLocalOffer
```

and firing `negotiationneeded` twice on the answerer side, which isn't even in `'stable'` state:

```
onmessage offer
adding audio track
adding video track
negotiating in have-remote-offer
negotiating in have-remote-offer
onmessage offer
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
  Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveLocalOffer
```

These extra events cause the havoc of reciprocal state errors seen on both ends here.

To be specific, Chrome violates two parts of the [spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dfn-update-the-negotiation-needed-flag) here:

1. *"Queue a task"* to fire this event. *"queueing prevents negotiationneeded from firing prematurely, in the common situation where multiple modifications to connection are being made at once."*
2. *If connection's signaling state is not `"stable"`, abort these steps [to fire the event].*

### Workaround

Working around *both* Chrome bugs requires (using `async`/`await` for brevity):

```
let negotiating = false;
pc.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
  try {
    if (negotiating || pc.signalingState != "stable") return;
    negotiating = true;
    /* Your async/await-using code goes here */
  } finally {
    negotiating = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you upvote this answer, don't forget to also ★ the [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740501).

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 75.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 81 and facing same issue even after applying workaround solution.