# Calling createAnswer doesn't change `signallingState`

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

Calling `createAnswer` doesn't change `signalingState`, it still  in `have-remote-offer`. What may be the possible reason for this.

```
    offerSdp = { "sdp": offerSdp, "type": "offer" };

    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerSdp)).then(() => {
        pc.createAnswer().then(answer => {
            //state still have-remote-offer
            pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer)).then(() => {
                deferred.resolve(answer.sdp)
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`createOffer`/`createAnswer` just create an offer/answer respectively (aka "description") and return them to you, to pass around. They do not affect [signalingState](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcsignalingstate-enum).

`setLocalDescription` and `setRemoteDescription` do:

[image]

If you check the state *after* those methods have resolved, then you should see the state you expect.

Note that, as the chart shows, only certain state transitions are allowed. For instance, `setLocalDecription` may only be called with an *answer* in `have-remote-offer` state. Calling it with an offer will error.

Comment: But i get this error while  `pc.setLocalDescription` :  Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveRemoteOffer

Comment: @Shashidhara See the chart. `setLocalDecription` may only be called with an answer in that state. In your question you mention `createOffer` but in your example you have `createAnswer`, which is it? Please improve your question to include what you're asking about so we may answer it satisfactorily, or ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It is createAnswer. Code in question is the actual code used in my application.

Comment: As i checked.. the state is proper. Still I get the previously mentioned error in comment.

Comment: @Shashidhara by any chance are you on Chrome and using `onnegotiationneeded`? If so, try Firefox. You might be hitting a Chrome bug. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035315/918910).